# Amplifying a pyranometer's small output using a single-supply amplifier

Tags: single-supply-op-amp, small-signal

I am making use of the[Apogee SP-110-SS Pyranometer](https://www.apogeeinstruments.com/content/SP-110-manual.pdf) which outputs 0.2 mV per Wm-2. This pyranometer gives its true output over two cables, described as a positive and a negative output, where the mV representation of irradiance is given by measuring the voltage difference between the positive and negative outputs.

I need to consolidate these two signals into one final value in a circuit so that I can send it to an ADC to be converted into a digital value for data storage. Is there a simple way that I can find the voltage difference between these two outputs using circuit elements so that I can send it to a more traditional amplifier? If there is no easy or cost-effective way to do so, would an instrumentation amplifier with a single supply voltage of 3.3V be able to amplify an input signal that is one part positive, another part negative, and in the millivolt range?

Answer (score 0):

The negative output is considered common as discussed on page 20, "Independent Verification of Functionality" in the manual you referenced. It appears that the output leads are connected to the light sensor directly, so the sensor is *floating*, i.e., not referenced to anything. The terminology regarding the output leads is just a matter of polarity of the signal output.

Depending on your noise environment, you may get by with an opamp with a high input impedance topology (see page 20, "Effect of Cable Length" for the discussion of input impedance of your amplifier). If your noise environment is bad, a FET-input instrumentation amplifier (perhaps an AD8220) may be necessary. If single supply is a must, you need to check the amplifier's common mode input voltage range and the output voltage range. I would recommend a split supply if you're dealing with low light levels.

Comment: The cable MUST be a shielded cable that is always used for audio. Then the two signal wires can have one of them as the shield and connected to the circuit's 0V.

Comment: Would a AD8223 be a good choice, then, if I need to implement this w/ 3.3V Single Supply ?
Data sheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8223.pdf

Comment: @JickMerrigan The AD8223 looks like a good choice. Unfortunately, there is no SPICE model for simulation. The AD8227, which is similar, but not quite as good, does have a SPICE model. You can use LTSpice (free simulator from Analog Devices) to simulate your circuit and see if it does what you need. Be careful of input bias currents with these models since you need a fairly high input impedance (data sheet recommends 1 megaohm which means using 500k input bias resistors). Be sure to read the data sheet carefully since you are in the realm of difficult design due to small signals.